# How to pass param {overwrite: true} in Brocfile.js

Tags: less, ember-cli, broccolijs

**info:**

```
ember-cli: 0.2.5,
ember-cli-less: 1.3.3,
```

I have the next error:

```
Merge error: file assets/mobile.css.map exists in mobile/tmp/caching-writer-dest-dir_ZcaW3C.tmp and /mobile/tmp/caching-writer-dest-dir_E4iROO.tmp
Pass option { overwrite: true } to mergeTrees in order to have the latter file win.
```

I tried what say in [this](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v0.0.41) post and this [other](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli-merge-trees). But I still without results.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since none of the methods mentioned in the previous links worked. I choose to modify the ember-cli-less package:

```
node_modules/ember-cli-less/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/index.js
```

I changed the line:

```
function TreeMerger (inputTrees, options) {
  if (!(this instanceof TreeMerger)) return new TreeMerger(inputTrees, options)
  if (!Array.isArray(inputTrees)) {
    throw new Error('Expected array, got ' + inputTrees)
  }
  this.inputTrees = inputTrees
  this.options = { overwrite: true } // <- This line
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this was bugging me all day.

Answer (score 1):

The mergeTrees module has an option for `overwrite`.

It's documented here: https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli-merge-trees#options

Here's an example:

```
return new MergeTrees([app.toTree(), fonts], { overwrite: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mac, can you try `find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete`?

I've a similar issue, and I was able to solve by deleting duplicate files.

Error message

```
Build failed.
Merge error: file .DS_Store exists in /Users/ember-proj/tmp/broccoli_merge_trees-input_base_path-qaWJUMIJ.tmp/0 and /Users/ember-proj/ai/tmp/broccoli_merge_trees-input_base_path-qaWJUMIJ.tmp/1
Pass option { overwrite: true } to mergeTrees in order to have the latter file win.
```

Comment: This helped me instantly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

update ember-cli-less to latest version (now 1.5.3), then pass config like this.

```
'ember-cli-less': {
  mergeTrees: {
    overwrite: true
  }
}
```

things would work